# How to remove evasi0n 7 jailbreak on ip4 iOS 7.0.4?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

I jailbroke my iPhone 4 iOS 7.0.4 (11B554a) with evasi0n 7. And that's the worse I did with my phone. I am new to iPhone and was just curious about jailbreaking. But that jailbreak corrupted many of my apps including iOS own apps.

I am very very happy with iPhone in its default iOS. I want to restore back to 7.0.4.

P.S: I tried "Erase all data and settings restore" from iPhone settings but the process stucks at spinning wheel after restart.

#

Update::

Ok. I did that. I downloaded ipsw of iOS 7.0.4 and tried to install it through shift+restore method through iTunes. But it keeps giving me error 21 again and again. And don't know about it.

Comment: Put your phone to DFU and connect to iTunes. Rest is self explanatory. You do not need to download ipsw of 7.0.4 separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempting to reset your jailbroken phone from your phone will break *everything*. You'll need to put your device in DFU mode and restore it with iTunes. Connect your device to iTunes, then hold the power and home button until the Apple logo shows, then keep holding home and let go of power. iTunes should prompt you to restore iOS.

Comment: I have updated the question. Kindly see